# Explanation of program

Tags: c

## What is the explanation of the output of this program?

```
int main ()
{

    int *mptr, m;

    int *nptr, n;

    m=10;

    n=0;

    mptr=&m;

    nptr=&n;

    printf("%i%i", m, n);

}

/* output is 100*/
```

Comment: You are confused that writing "10" and "0" results in "100"?

Answer (score 0):

this program makes an integer 10 and an integer 0 and then prints them out as a string '10' + '0' so the final output is '100'

It also keeps pointers to both ints but these pointers aren't used

Answer (score 0):

1. `int *mptr` and `nptr` are pointers of type `int`
2. `m` and `n` are variables of type `int`. `m=10;` you are storing the value `10` in variable `m`.
3. `mptr=&m` is storing the address of m in mptr pointer. This effectively causes `mptr` to "point to" `m`. Same with `nptr`, but it points to `n`.
4. `printf("%i%i", m, n);` `printf` means print-formatted. `%i` is format specifier to print an integer. Prints the values of `m` `(10)` and `n` `(0)` next to each other, giving output `100`.